# Array data per user

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to return a sum from the values held within an array.

For example the sum would be:

'Answer One => 0 => 0' + 'Answer Two => 0 => 0'

And the return value would be a sum of the values, in this example of question one, it would be 1500.

Is there a way to adapt the following to return the value within the for loop?

**Current Output:**

```
"answer_one" => array:3 [
0 => array:3 [▼
  0 => 1500
  1 => 0
  2 => 0
]
1 => array:3 [▼
  0 => 0
  1 => 788
  2 => 0
]
2 => array:3 [▼
  0 => 0
  1 => 0
  2 => 651
]
]
  "answer_two" => array:3 [
    0 => array:3 [▼
      0 => 0
      1 => 1500
      2 => 0
    ]
    1 => array:3 [▶]
    2 => array:3 [▶]
  ]
```

**Current Code**

```
$users = \App\User::where('role_id', '!=', 1)->get();

    for ($k = 1; $k < setting('amount_of_questions'); $k++) {
        $f = str_replace(' ', '', $this->convertNumberToWord($k));
        $tests = 'question_' . $f . '_answer';
        $atts[$tests] = array();

        foreach ($users as $userr) {
            if ($userr->$tests == 'For') {
                $test = array(intval($userr->question_value), 0, 0);
                array_push($atts[$tests], $test);
            } else if ($userr->$tests == 'Against') {
                $test = array(0, intval($userr->question_value), 0);
                array_push($atts[$tests], $test);
            } else if ($userr->$tests == 'Abstain') {
                $test = array(0, 0, intval($userr->question_value));
                array_push($atts[$tests], $test);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for. Can you provide a sample of the desired output? Also, can you include your own attempt at doing this and describe what problems you ran into?

Comment: @El_Vanja the detail is all in the post..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read of https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

```
$sum = array("answer_one" => array("For" => 0, "Against" => 0, "Abstain" => 0), "answer_two" => array("For" => 0, "Against" => 0, "Against" => 0));
foreach ($atts as $questionNum => $questionAnswers) { // $questionNum = answer_one then answer_two
   foreach($questionAnswers as $questionAnswer => $answerValues) { // each users response to a question (it will be an array with 3 values)
      foreach($answerValues as $answerNum => $answerValue) {
          if($answerValue > 0) {
             if($answerNum == 0) {
                $sum[$questionNum]["For"] += $answerValue;
             }else if($answerNum == 1) {
                $sum[$questionNum]["Against"] += $answerValue;
             }else if($answerNum == 2) {
                $sum[$questionNum]["Abstain"] += $answerValue;
             }
          }
      }
   }
}

$questionNum = 1;
foreach($sum as $questionAnswers) {
   foreach($questionAnswers as $questionAnswer => $questionAnswerTotal) {
      echo 'The score for question '.$questionNum.' '.$questionAnswer.' is '.$questionAnswerTotal.'. ';
   }
   $questionNum++;
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/MlaXm

Comment: The calculation is slightly wrong. This is returning the total value for the nested array. What I need to do is get all of the values of [0] and add those together, then [1] etc. make sense?

Comment: Yes, exactly that, is this possible?!

Comment: Thats great @The Codesee is there any way I can group them, so 'The score for QUESTION 1 FOR IS' - 'The score for QUESTION 1 AGAINST IS' ...

Comment: It might be structured wrong, but essentially in my database I have fields for answers, 'question_one_answer', question_two_answer, etc. Each user votes a value which is held in another field. There are three possible answers, For-Against-Abstain. If a user votes for on question 1, the value is assigned to that. If they vote Against on question 2 it is also assigned to that. 

We're trying to calculate the total value for the question. So if there are 5 users and they have voted 'For' on question one, we need to add those values and get a total. If 2 users voted 'Against' - those totals..

Comment: End goal is to have something like: Question 1 (For): $q1fortotal; Question 1 (Against): $q1againsttotal; Question 1 (Abstain): $q1abstaintotal; Question 2 (For): $q2fortotal; Question 2 (Against): $q2againsttotal; Question 2 (Abstain): $q2abstaintotal;

Comment: This could be the way i've structured it wrong, I'm not sure whether I'm supposed to loop over the questions and then the users, or the users and then the questions. I've been through the woods with this one it's fried my brain. Basically if you see the original post, in my users loop, If the answer is 'For' im assigning the value of the user, then a 0 for Against, and a 0 for Abstain. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Hey mate, is there any way you could show me how to loop through this; $sum = array("answer_one" => array("For" => 0, "Against" => 0, "Abstain" => 0), "answer_two" => array("For" => 0, "Against" => 0, "Against" => 0)); - you see in my original post under 'current code' I'm running a loop on $k

Comment: @Bill Hey, not sure I understand what you you mean, the code does loop through `$sum`